# HP Elitebook G3 mousepad ghost right click

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I am facing a very strange issue, I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop everything works fine except mousepad, when I start my computer mousepad works fine but after some time it start clicking right click automatically even If I attached USB mouse.

I have disabled Touchpad from settings but still ghost right click triggering, It gets normal again when I switch to Virtual console and switch back to GUI.

I also tried updating drivers but did not get any success, It does no seem like hardware issue rather it could be kernel compatibility issue.